# Prove that f(x) is uniformly continuous

Tags: analysis, uniform-continuity

Show that $f(x)=x^2cos(\frac{1}{x^2})$ on (0,1).

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $x,y \epsilon (0,1)$. $| f(y) - f(x)| = |y^2cos(\frac{1}{y^2}) - x^2cos(\frac{1}{x^2})|$.

After this I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You have to show uniform continuity on a set. What set? Also, is $f(x)=x^3 \cos(1/x^2)$ or $f(x)=x^2 \cos(1/x^2)$?

Comment: I forgot to include the interval, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to show a function is uniformly continuous is to show it is *Lipschitz*. That is, to show that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L |x-y|$ on a set $A$, where $L$ is some constant independent of $x,y$. A common way to show a function is Lipschitz is the use the mean value theorem: $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(\xi)||x-y|$. For $1>\eta>0$, show that your function $f(x)$ is Lipschitz on $[\eta, 1)$.

Show also that for $x, y \in (0, \eta]$ that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 2 \eta^2$.

Combine both of these facts to show that $f$ is uniformly continuous. (That is, given $\epsilon>0$, pick $\eta>0$ and then pick $\delta > 0$ so that $|f(x)-f(y)|$ is small. You will have to find a way to "bridge the gap" between the intervals $(0, \eta]$ and $(\eta, 1)$. That is, you have to deal with the case $x\in (0, \eta]$ and $y \in (\eta, 1)$. Add and subtract and use the triangle inequality.)

[P.S. If this is homework, please remember to cite all help you receive.]

Answer (score -1):

If you define $f(0) = 0$, you can prove that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I seem to recall something about continuous functions on compact intervals being uniformly continuous.

Comment: But $[0,1)$ is not compact.

Comment: The function (as provided) is continuous on $(0,1]$.

Comment: I know what you are trying to say, but technically, the function as provided is defined on $(0,1)$. If your hints are not explicit and require a few more steps, they may be viewed as low quality answers. If you explain a bit more in your answer, the low-quality flags can be cleared. You can still hint, but perhaps give a bit more. (I have cleared the flags BTW)